# Should I use the DotNetOpenAuth OAuthAuthenticationModule or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

In dnoa's web rp application template for visual studio, there is an HttpModule named OAuthAuthenticationModule. However, I can't tell how it's used, since it doesn't look like the vs template (the MVC one anyway) does any OAuth authentication out of the box.

The samples in version 3.5.0.10213 of DotNetOpenAuth don't seem to use any custom HttpModules. Instead, there are different consumer classes for Facebook, Twitter, etc, which wrap the TokenManager calls. I can only get these consumers to work by removing the references to this module from web.config (as documented [here](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/ded72c3d6739693d)).

If I want to authenticate against different OAuth providers (i.e. user chooses either Facebook or Twitter), should I follow the XyzproviderConsumer examples in the 10213 build? Or should I be using this HttpModule instead?